# PC boot no signal

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot

So when the PC boots up, is shows the BIOS message and after that the led of the monitor switches between red/blue but after a few minutes(like 4-5min) boots up..what's the main problem?

OS: Windows Xp SP3

The funny thing is that on Windows 7  doesn't have this problem, but I need to run Windows Xp since it's an old machine...

I will take the Video card out and clean it, mabe that solved the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitor does not get the right video signal.

Either signal goes to other output (most likely set in BIOS) or monitor does not support that (640x480) mode as opposed to 800x600 of W7

Comment: I found out that It doesn't show the boot logo of windows xp...you know windows logo and the progress bar